# GAS gadget inserted to googleSite... for non-google accounts

Tags: google-apps-script

I think this is the same as my question: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=852

But just to be clear:  **Google apps scripts won't run on a Google Site without a google/gmail user being signed in?**

...are there other google products where GAS can be deployed for non-google accounts?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 1):

False. You can embed an Apps Script in a Google Site using Insert > Script Gadget. Just be sure that the publishing setting is set to "Anyone, even anonymous".

Answer (score 1):

You've got two different levels of user identity at work here, if not three or more.  I will try to pull them apart for you in a clear way.

1. Google Sites can work for users of Google and non users.  It depends entirely on the sharing settings for that site.  If you share it with the world, it will be shared and indexed by search engines.  If you share with anyone with link, search engines won't index it but no user will have to sign in to use the site.
2. What you are embedding in a Google site may have it's own user identity issues.  The easiest way to manage these is to go into 'Publish' menu, and 'deploy as Webapp'. You will then see a menu that asks which account the script should be run under, essentially you or the user.  And then which people to allow access, which you would select 'Anyone, even anonymous'.

This will run that app as your account, but allow anyone to call it.  Works great for allowing the public access to a form created in GAS.

Now the other problems.  It may be possible for you to have code in your GAS that specifically calls for a user.  In that case all of the prior settings don't matter.  When the script looks for a user and finds nothing valid it will error.  These call are pretty obvious though and are more rarely used. (At least in my experience.)

But, in short, yes!  You can certainly embed GAS into Google sites to be called by anonymous users.

Example of mine: https://sites.google.com/site/greenmountainretreat/sign-up

Comment: Thank you for the feedback...great news.  I should have seen that in the deployment options.

Answer (score 0):

The [issue you are referring to](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=852) is about inserting i-frame gadgets into **non-Google** sites... please don't confuse things... and read the issue report thoroughly.

*If you want another [example](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home)...*